# Output contents of clicked cell in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to modify:

```
$(".rank").click(function(event){

    alert(this.id);

});
```

to alert value inside of `<td class="rank"></td>` instead of it's id?

Comment: What have you tried? What have you researched? What is your problem with the research you came up with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **[`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/)** for getting text content inside `td`

```
$(".rank").click(function(event){
    alert($(this).text());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here it is.

```
$(".rank").click(function(event){

    alert($(this).html());

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a live example using `$('selector').text()`

```css
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

.rank{
  cursor:pointer;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>Rank</td>  
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td class="rank">2</td>  
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Aaron</td>
    <td class="rank">12</td>  
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Jenny</td>
    <td class="rank">18</td>  
   </tr>
 
</table>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    
    $(".rank").click(function(){
         alert($(this).text());
    });
    
   });
 </script>
```